# Javascript Analysis tool for code dependencies

Tags: javascript, dependencies, code-analysis

I was wondering if there exist javascript analysis tools that analyse a bunch of javascript files and determines which javascript files depend on each other. For example:

file A:

```
function testObject() {
}
```

file B:

```
var test = testObject();
```

Then I should get that file B depends on A since B uses function testObject defined in file A. Something similar exists for node, which is [madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge), but I was wondering if this also exists for the described case. Madge seems to only work for javascript files that specifically use `require` to import the functionality.

Comment: yeah, it's called the console. most major browsers have some version of a console built in. in Firebug for example, you can view the "Net" (network) tab and then click "scripts" and you can see all the scripts that are loaded.

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool that will graph dependencies into an image if wanted. Hope it  helps. [MaDGe](https://github.com/pahen/madge)

> Create graphs from your CommonJS, AMD or ES6 module dependencies. Could also be useful for finding circular dependencies in your code. Tested on Node.js and RequireJS projects. Dependencies are calculated using static code analysis. CommonJS dependencies are found using James Halliday's detective, for AMD I'm using amdetective and for ES6 detective-es6 is used. Modules written in CoffeeScript with extension .coffee are supported and will automatically be compiled on-the-fly.